# Unknown filesystem Grub rescue error

Tags: windows-7, ubuntu, grub, bootloader

I have a lenovo z570, and I installed Ubuntu 12.04 alongside Windows 7. Recently all my games that I've been playing stop responding due to a AppCrash.

I searched for the error on Google and they said it had something to do with Ubuntu. So I deleted the partition. After restarting my laptop i get the "unknown filesystem" grub rescue error.

I tried using a windows CD to boot, but it can't.

Please help.

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to fix this by reinstalling GRUB.

Boot from a linux live cd, open a terminal and type:

```
$ sudo update-grub
```

You should see something like (emphasis mine):

> Generating grub.cfg ...
>      **Found Windows 7 (loader) on /dev/sdaX**
>      done

**If you do not see a line containing Found Windows 7 do not continue.** There is a different problem.

If you *do* see a line saying that windows 7 was found continue to the next step:

```
$ sudo grub-install /dev/sda
```

**This will remove the windows bootloader (if there, I think you have already removed it) and replace it with the linux bootloader GRUB.**

Now, restart your machine, you should be presented with a normal GRUB menu enabling to chose windows. If you want to completely remove GRUB search for a howto on restoring an [MBR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MBR) on windows.

Answer (score 0):

Check the links I think useful for you.

[Help Ubuntu](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2)
and 
[Ask Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/142300/how-to-fix-error-unknown-filesystem-grub-rescue)

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes you can use the linux live CD to boot from a system in this state. Reboot with the Live CD in the computer then when the boot menu comes up choose "Boot from first Hard disk"